# requestBody is not availble

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-restcontroller

RestController:

```java
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/path", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public TestModel post(@RequestBody TestModel model) {
    return model;
}
```

Model looks like this:

```java
public class TestModel implements Serializable {


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String id;

}
```

Post this JSon

```json
{
  "id" : 4711
}
```

postman looks like this

[image: 1]

get The response:

```json
{
    "type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Required request body is missing: public ....,
    "path": "/path",
    "message": "error.http.400"
}
```

It looks like something is blocking the `@RequestBody`, because `@RequestParam` and `@PathParam` is working well... Does someone know what is the reason for that issue?

Comment: Have you tried to quote 4711 as it is a string in your java model and not an integer/number. Like `{"id":"4711"}`

Comment: yes, I tried out, it doesnt make a change of the result ( Ichange after my testing the type from int to String)..

Comment: for me it looks like, that something blocks the RequestBody data...
is there anywhere builtin security option to block @RequestBody ?

Comment: it does also not work when try to get String instead of TestModel like this:

post(@RequestBody String model)

Comment: Have you raised the log level on server for logger "org.springframework.web.*"? Did you try same request using a simpler REST client like JHipster swagger-ui or curl?

Comment: @Gaäl Thanks; 
I tried with curl, its working, but not with postman and other rest clients...
do you have an idea how I can call swagger-ui? what ist usr for this? /swagger-ui.html is not working

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe a problem of type. In your postman, you set a number value whereas in the code, you're waiting for a String. Try to put a String value in postman for instance or change id type to "int" in your code .